# Remove command removed my important documents on El Capitan

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I have just made a stupid mistake that cost me a lot. I tried to uninstall a software on my Mac, it is this one here: [Uninstallation Ureka](http://ssb.stsci.edu/ureka/1.0beta5/docs/uninstallation.html) and I followed the instructions in the link. On the terminal, I typed exactly as in the documentation:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.ureka
```

when I suddenly realised after a couple of seconds that this deletes all my important files! I killed the process before it ended but I think it deleted my home folder. All my school work, important files were there.
Is there a way I can get them back ? What happened? Could you help me somehow?

Comment: Are you using Time Machine or any other backup regime to safeguard yourself from these kinds of disastrous errors?

Comment: I had Time Machine but at that time it was not turned on...

Comment: What did that command do? Shouldn't it have just removed Ureka?

Comment: If you typed the command by hand, it is possible that you hit a space character after the `$HOME/` by mistake. I tried copy/pasting the command from the webpage you referenced, and it would have worked correctly.

Comment: Yes, I think that is possible. So what can I do in this case?

Comment: It does not matter of Time Machine was turned on when you deleted the files it matters when TM was last turned on and thus when it backed up the files

Comment: I do not know if it was ever turned on. How can I check that?

Comment: This is what happens...

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a way to get my files back?

Comment: Without a backup, there is nothing to restore. If you were prudent enough to shutdown the computer as soon as you realized the mistake, it _might_ be possible for a data recovery company, or the app [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) to get some or most of your data back; but if you continued to use the computer (logged in as another user, for example) for any length of time, crucial data may have been written over.

Comment: I continued to use the computer for a couple of hours, half a day maybe and then it was shut down. Does this mean that all my data have been written over?

Answer (score 1):

Except that the command from the Ureka Web site doesn't do that, of course.  So what did you *actually* type?  Perhaps something more like

```
rm -rf $HOME / .ureka
```

Note the extra spaces.

In any case, if files were actually removed, learn from the experience, restore your backup, and move on.